# how to create image like this image?

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing android news app and how can I make imageview like below on the imageview on the top and there are should be any library or ways to achieve that

[image]

Comment: Research on Drawables, Shapes, and then once you have learned about that, possibly create a white non-transparent triangle, and put that at the bottom of your image (on top). That's one way to do it I guess.

Comment: are you sure about that

Comment: I'm never sure about anything; even things that I made and that work :) But truth be told, that's what I'd *try* to do first; and because I have to wait for an hour, I'm going to try it now ;)

Comment: but regarding to triangle how can I get exact triangle image like that I researched about 1 days did not find anything

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView You can use this library to give your `View` a custom shape..then load image in that `View`

Comment: You just need to play with the shape to get the right angles, or you can even create a vector triangle, tint it white, and put it as `foreground` of your image view

Answer (score 3):

### Attempt 1: Using a simple Shape drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="10"
                android:toDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="-230%"
                android:pivotY="14%" >
            <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid
                        android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

(this took me 5 minutes, so maybe there are better ways to do this shape).

This would be the layout, notice the `foreground` property pointing to my "shape" above.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/my_shape"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxx" />
```

It looks like this:

[image: Sample]

([Original Wikipedia image source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/F-16_June_2008.jpg/1200px-F-16_June_2008.jpg))

### Attempt 2: Using a custom SVG

I fired Inkscape, and made a quick triangle (I left it semi-opaque so you can see it)

[image: Inkscape]

Imported it as a Vector asset called `ic_bad_triangle`, and then added it to the foreground of the image...

... (omitted all attributes of course)

```
    <ImageView
            ...
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_bad_triangle" />
```

And it looks like this:

[image: WithSVG]

obviously you'd have to tweak your vector assets to match your designs and sizes, but you get the idea, no need to introduce a library.

The last image's triangle is obviously semi-transparent there, so you can see it. Considering this took me 25 minutes, I hope it gets you in the right direction.

### UPDATE: I polished the triangle:

```
<vector android:height="35.357143dp" android:viewportHeight="297"
    android:viewportWidth="210" android:width="25dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M-0.084,298.008H216.193L-0.421,258.091Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt" android:strokeLineJoin="miter" android:strokeWidth="0.64384729"/>
</vector>
```

and it now looks like this:

[image: Better]